# What does ":+" mean in Scala

Tags: scala

I saw some Scala code written as:

```
 def next(): Array[String] = someVariable.next() :+ iterator.key
```

Where `someVariable` has a method `next()` to get the next line and the iterator is of type `Iterator[String]`.

What does `:+` mean here?

Comment: Is there some reason why you didn't just look this up in the scala doc? http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps@:+(elem:A):Array[A] The API documentation is fairly comprehensive, and my "go to" place for questions like this.

Comment: It's cool new docs (2.12) give you this nice search feature http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.0-M4/index.html?search=:+

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul the time you took to write this stuff, could have answered him in a better way...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`:+` is a method on whatever type is returned by `someVariable.next()`.

Presumably it's [`scala.Array.:+`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.Array@:+[B>:T](elem:B)(implicitevidence$2:scala.reflect.ClassTag[B]):Array[B])

> A copy of this array with an element appended.

---

This is also a case where an IDE would help you greatly. With Intellij for example, you could use the "Quick doc" or "Jump to definition" commands on `:+` and immediately find out where it came from. I've found that tooling to be invaluable in writing scala.

Answer (score 48):

On Scala Collections there is usually `:+` and `+:`.
Both add an element to the collection. `:+` appends `+:` prepends.
A good reminder is, `:` is where the Collection goes.

There is as well `colA ++: colB` to concat collections, where the `:` side collection determines the resulting type.
If a `:++` exists, it is the same as `++`. In both cases the left side collection determines the type of result.

Comment: What is difference between `++` and `:++`?

Answer (score 5):

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4) :+ 400
res27: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 400)
```

Comment: While this code  may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: And with questions this old it can be quite helpful to explain how your answer is different from the existing answers.